# SQL get 3 different values from separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a sql join where I'm trying to get 3 values from another table at the same time. Below is the data: (SiteID which is Site, HomeId which is home, VisitorId which is Visitor). I have tried

```
Select GameDate 
From Games 
INNER JOIN Schools ON Schools.SchoolId = Games.SiteId 
Where Games.GameId = '1'`
```

But it only gets SiteId, and not HomeId, or VisitorId

```
Games table
GameId  GameDate    SiteId   HomeId   VisitorId
  1      1/5/15         2        2          1
  2      1/7/15         1        1          2
  3      1/8/15         1        1          2

Schools table
SchoolId    SchoolName
   1         SchoolA
   2         SchoolB
```

This is the information I want to get

```
Date       Site        Home      Visitor
1/5/15    SchoolB    SchoolB    SchoolA
1/7/15    SchoolA    SchoolA    SchoolB
1/8/15    SchoolA    SchoolA    SchoolB
```

Comment: YOu are going to have to join to the Schools table 3 times, once for each ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to join to the same table multiple times and use table aliases:

```
SELECT Games.GameDate AS Date,
    SiteSchool.SchoolName AS Site,
    HomeSchool.SchoolName AS Home,
    VisitorSchool.SchoolName AS Visitor
FROM Games
INNER JOIN Schools SiteSchool
    ON SiteSchool.SchoolId = Games.SiteId 
INNER JOIN Schools HomeSchool
    ON HomeSchool.SchoolId = Games.HomeId 
INNER JOIN Schools VisitorSchool
    ON VisitorSchool.SchoolId = Games.VisitorId 
WHERE Games.GameId = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the `Schools` table three times, one for each key:

```
Select g.GameDate , s.SchoolName as Site, h.SchoolName as home, v.SchoolName as visitor
From Games g INNER JOIN
     Schools s
     ON s.SchoolId = g.SiteId INNER JOIN
     Schools h
     on h.SchoolId = g.HomeId INNER JOIN
     Schools v
     on v.SchoolId = g.VisitorId
Where Games.GameId = 1;
```

When you have the same table used multiple times in the `from` clause, you need to use table aliases to distinguish among them.  IN this case, the aliases are "s" for site, "h" for home, and "v" for visitor.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do three Joins for Site, Home and Visitor school names.

Here is a working example

```
With Games As
(
          Select 1 GameId, '1/5/2015' GameDate, 2 SiteId, 2 HomeId, 1 VisitorId
    Union Select 2 GameId, '1/7/2015' GameDate, 1 SiteId, 1 HomeId, 2 VisitorId
    Union Select 3 GameId, '1/8/2015' GameDate, 1 SiteId, 1 HomeId, 2 VisitorId
),
Schools As
(
    Select 1 SchoolId, 'SchoolA' SchoolName
    Union Select 2 SchoolId, 'SchoolB' SchoolName
)
Select 
    GameDate, 
    SiteSchool.SchoolName Site,
    HomeSchool.SchoolName Home,
    VisitorSchool.SchoolName Visitor
From Games G
Inner Join Schools as SiteSchool 
    On G.SiteId = SiteSchool.SchoolId
Inner Join Schools as HomeSchool 
    On G.SiteId = HomeSchool.SchoolId
Inner Join Schools as VisitorSchool 
    On G.SiteId = VisitorSchool.SchoolId
```

Answer (score 1):

@HLGEM is correct.

```
Select g.GameDate
     , s1.SchoolName as Site
     , s2.SchoolName as Home
     , s3.SchoolName as Visitor
From Games g INNER JOIN 
Schools s1 ON Schools.SchoolId = Games.SiteId INNER JOIN
Schools s2 ON Schools.SchoolId = Games.HomeId INNER JOIN
Schools s3 ON Schools.SchoolId = Games.VisitorId
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `INNER JOIN Schools` 3 times.

```
Select GameDate, S1.SchoolName, S2.SchoolName, S3.SchoolName
From Games 
INNER JOIN Schools S1 ON S1.SchoolId = Games.SiteId 
INNER JOIN Schools S2 ON S2.SchoolId = Games.HomeId
INNER JOIN Schools S3 ON S3.SchoolId = Games.VisitorId
Where Games.GameId = '1'
```